# Netlogo Rnd Extension: loading probability weights through Input boxes

Tags: netlogo

I want a random item reported from this list:

```
set probability-list [["residential" 0.60] ["commercial" 0.30] ["industrial" 0.10]]
```

The way they are called is:

```
set land-use first rnd:weighted-one-of-list probability-list last
```

But I want the weight of each item to be inputted by the user through input boxes in the model's interface, not in the code itself. For this, I added an input box for each item called Res, Com and Ind. So the code for the list is now:

```
set probability-list [["residential" Res] ["commercial" Com] ["industrial" Ind]]
```

but Netlogo highlights code with the weight name and the message "Expected a literal value". Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a list literal in NetLogo, you can only put other literal items (strings, numbers, booleans) that you type into the code in that list.

To make a "dynamic" list using variables, you have to use the `list` primitive with parenthesis:

```
set probability-list (list (list "residential" Res) (list "commercial" Com) (list "industrial" Ind))
```

This is outlined in [the NetLogo programming guide under lists](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists).